# How to calculate the hourly number of observation?

Tags: loops, datetime

I need to calculate the hourly number of observations for a data set consists of around 100000 dates. each data-time represents one observation.

For example, I need to calculate the hourly events from 2018-11-25-20-35-00 to 2018-11-27-01-35-00.

Additionally, where there is no event there should be an output of zero.
[The sample data set is shown in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKKPr.jpg)

Comment: which language are you intending to use for that? also, could you please add sample data and some code you tried as text instead of image?

Comment: Usually you create (possibly virtually) a new field with a hourly timestamp (e.g. with some hour function, or using a timestamp (second) truncate, modulo 3600). Then you count the row with same hours. How to do it, it depends on the language you use, and nearly for sure: not with a loops (as your tag). Please edit your question (and tags) so we can help you better. Now we cannot help you: we lack of information (and please include a very small subset of data in the question: avoid external links)

Comment: I am working in python. A simple data set is like

Comment: I am working in python. A simple data set is as below: Suppose, I need to calculate the event between 2018-09-19-20-18-35 to 2018-09-21--20-18-35                                              2018 9 19 19 9 43.01
2018 9 19 19 29 15.66
2018 9 19 20 9 56.01
2018 9 19 20 41 42.99
2018 9 19 21 38 49.77
2018 9 20 2 39 9.72
2018 9 20 5 4 3.55
2018 9 20 5 41 44.94
2018 9 20 6 45 46.49                                                                      
2018 9 21 19 31 18.34
2018 9 21 19 56 47.78
2018 9 21 20 35 34.29
2018 9 21 22 32 31.35
2018 9 21 22 57 44.27